# Data Source setting in Connection String

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, connection-string

Consider these two connection strings that are different only by their Data Source settings:

```
Data Source=OEM-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=<databasename>;
Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;
User ID=<userid>;Password=<password>;Connect Timeout=30

Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=<databasename>;
Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;
User ID=<userid>;Password=<password>;Connect Timeout=30
```

Why is it that when I use the first, I get thrown the error

> *Login failed for user  Reason: An attempt to login using
>   SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows
>   authentication only. [CLIENT: ]*

I'm using SQL Server 2008 Express and the server is configured for mixed authentication and I've tripled check that using

(a) `master.dbo.xp_instance_regread`,
(b) `SERVERPROPERTY()` and
(c) `master.sys.xp_loginconfig`.

Also, enabling the `sa` login doesn't make any difference.

Let me know if additional data is required. Thanks.

Comment: At a guess, you have several SQL Server instances installed, not just one. The default one (also accessed using `.`) has SQL Authentication setup and enabled, where the `SQLExpress` instance doesn't.

Comment: You're quite right, but I am perplexed. I have a SQLEXPRESS instance and another MSSQLSERVER instance, so I stopped the SQLEXPRESS instance and I tried to get a valid connection string for the MSSQLSERVER. But then in that valid connection string, I can use "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=<databasename>;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<userid>;Password=<password>;Connect Timeout=30"
 but not 
"Data Source=OEM-PC\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=<databasename>;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<userid>;Password=<password>;Connect Timeout=30"

Comment: I thought the proper syntax is "myServerName\myInstanceName" from  [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008), so is there a naming convention I missed that "OEM-PC\MSSQLSERVER" wouldn't work?

Comment: @Oded: If you put your comment as an answer, I will tick it. You were spot on with the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I think I know now why "OEM-PC\MSSQLSERVER" doesn't work. According to [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2525/steps-to-change-the-server-name-for-a-sql-server-machine/), "When connecting to SQL Server, we use the physical server name for the default instance and physical server name\INSTANCE Name for a named instance." Running SELECT SERVERPROPERTY ('InstanceName') on MSSQLSERVER instance returns NULL which means its the default, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have several different instances of SQL Server installed.

The default one (also accessed using .) has SQL Authentication setup and enabled, where the SQLExpress instance doesn't.

Use [SQL Server Configuration Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx) to find out what instances you have and to configure them correctly.